# Splitting an address string with regex

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

How to split a string like this with a regular expression?

> Route de la Comba 32  1484 Aumont (FR)
>
> Chemin de la Vignetta 1  1617 Remaufens (FR)
>
> Route du Village 136  1609 Besencens (FR)

- **Address:** Route de la Comba 32
- **Postal code:** 1484
- **City:** Aumont (FR)

**NB: Between 32 and 1484 there are 2 spaces (displayed as one space in this question)**

Comment: Can a city be two words?  This gets ugly quickly.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
preg_match('/^(.+?)\h{2}(\d{4,5})\h+(.+)$/', $inputString, $matches);
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  (.+?)     : group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy, address
  \h{2}     : 2 horizontal spaces
  (\d{4,5}) : group 2, 4 upto 5 digits, postal code
  \h+       : 1 horizontal space
  (.+)      : group 3, 1 or more any character, city
$           : end of line
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always the same you could try using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with a double whitespace:

```
$str = "Route de la Comba 32  1484 Aumont (FR)";
$splitByDoubleSpace = explode("  ", $str);
$splitBySingleSpace = explode(" ", $splitByDoubleSpace[1]);
$city = implode(" ", array_slice($splitBySingleSpace, 1)); // Return the array except the first entry

echo sprintf(
    'Address: %s<br>Postal code: %s<br>City: %s',
    $splitByDoubleSpace[0],
    $splitBySingleSpace[0],
    implode(" ", array_slice($splitBySingleSpace, 1))
);
```

That would give you:

```
Address: Route de la Comba 32
Postal code: 1484
City: Aumont (FR)
```

[Demo Php](https://3v4l.org/lvVar)